# In unity c# script why ThirdPersonCharacter not exist?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace UnityStandradAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    public class BasicAi : MonoBehaviour {

        public NavMeshAgent agent;
        public 
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {

        }
    }
}
```

The second public when i start to type ThirdPerson i only have ThirdPerson but not ThirdPersonCharacter.

I should be able to type: public ThirdPersonCharacter but i only have two options ThirdPerson and ThirdPersonOrbitCam.

Comment: type the name of script in project window search to check if the script is imported with standard assets. If you can't find the ThirdPersonCharacter script. Then re-import Standard assets.

Comment: @UmairM i searched and it found ThirdPersonCharacter.cs in C:\Users\bout0_000\Documents\My First Game\Assets\Standard Assets\Characters\ThirdPersonCharacter\Scripts

Comment: @UmairM And the script i'm using now that can't find the ThirdPersonCharacter is under Assets in a new folder i created name My Scripts.

Comment: save your current file and go back to unity to see if there is any error so far. sometimes if you have syntax error in your code, it doesn't show you reference of classes in when you type. Even if its not showing the reference of that class just type full name and save the file. if file exists it wont show any error

Comment: @UmairM i closed the editor and opened again the MonoDevelop editor. This is the tree of my solution project screenshot you can see the tree on the left. ( i cant upload here yet images so its in a link ). http://i68.tinypic.com/vheutz.jpg Maybe something is wrong with where i created the script the BasicAi.cs ?

Comment: Why do you need to put this script in `namespace UnityStandradAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson`?

Comment: Can you see any syntax error when you go to unity editor?

Comment: @UmairM i found the problem iti s syntax error or mistype by me: The namespace in the ThirdPersonCharacter is: UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson and what i wrote in my script was: UnityStandradAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson i did "rad" instead "ard" anyway now it's working. Sorry for all the mess.

Comment: @UmairM the namespace in the ThirdPersonCharacter script was UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson thats whay i did the same name space in my BasicAi script.  It's wrong to give the same namespace ?